# sorting algorithm with least time complexity for already sorted array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I got a question that which type of sorting algorithm will have least time complexity when we are given an already sorted array.

Comment: `if(isSorted(list)) return; anySortAlgorithmYouLike(list);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a homework question, but I'd say one very simple algorithm that is time efficient on sorted or only slightly unsorted lists is [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Sorted, the time complexity is O(n). That said, there are many sorting algorithms that have similar time complexity for the best case scenario (i.e. already sorted), and bubble sort has a worst case of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Read the [`Performance` section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Performance) of Wikipedia's bubble sort page to find out why insertion sort is probably a better choice.  Insertion sort is also O(n) when the data are already sorted, and does better when the data are strongly ordered but not completely sorted.

Comment: All true, my recommendation of bubble sort is based on its ease of implementation and fulfillment of the basic criteria laid out by the question asker: that it is computationally efficient on a sorted array. In practice, there are many algorithms that are superior to bubble sort.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia has a table showing a [comparison of the best, average and worst-case performance of many different sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms). Here's an excerpt:

[image]

There are plenty of algorithms that have () running times for best-case inputs (i.e., pre-sorted data). However, most of them (like bubble sort, for example) have (²) running times for average and worst-case inputs. This is something you really want to avoid. Sorting a million items with one of these algorithms will take an eternity.

Fortunately, a few of these algorithms have ( log ) average and worst-case running times. These are as follows:

- [Cubesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubesort)
- [Smoothsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort)
- [Block sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort)

I would recommend using one of these.